# Calling a module after importing its parent package

Tags: python, python-import

I've been trying to figure out how to call a module after importing its parent package.

The directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── main
│   └── pkg
│       └── file.py
└── another_main
```

**NOTE:** All the packages contain `__init__.py` file and all the necessary path variables are set. I've not shown it here as this is just a dummy structure.

If I do:

```
from main import pkg
pkg.file
```

This doesn't work and throws `AttributeError: module 'pkg' has no attribute 'file'`

But if first I do:

```
from main.pkg import file
```

After that I can do:

```
from main import pkg
pkg.file  # --> Now this doesn't throw AttributeError
```

Is there a way I can call `file` like `pkg.file` without doing `from main.pkg import file`?

**P.S.:** I want to use `pkg.file` in my script so that in future I can recall that I called `file` from `pkg` and not `some_other_pkg`.

Comment: Maybe you can try - `from main import pkg.file`

Comment: I do not know if this works. But you can try it

Comment: It throws syntax error under the dot between pkg and file

Comment: You can try importing in the `__init__.py` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `__init__.py` of `main/pkg` you would have to import `file`:

```py
# pkg/__init__.py

import pkg.file

# EDIT: if the import above does not work, use this instead

from . import file
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem. If I edit the `__init__.py` file, I can't even import `pkg`. It yells `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg'`. Could you be a little descriptive on how to make import statements after I edit the `__init__.py`?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually `main.pkg.file`

Comment: This way it automatically imports `file` as I call `from main import pkg`. But I don't want this. I need to be able to use `pkg.file` (if possible) in my script after importing `pkg` as I've stated in the question.

Comment: [This](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) might also help

Comment: @YashvanderBamel As written in this answer, you need to do `from . import file` inside `main/pkg/__init__.py`, otherwise it won't be an attribute of that module.